# How to calculate results in multiple tables with Eloquent ORM

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm start learning MySQL and have some problem with selecting and calculating im multiple tables.

I have 2 tables:

First table "places"

```
id | name       | 
1  | restaurant |
```

Second table "ratings"

```
id | expert   | place_id | design | personal | cooking 
1  | expert 1 |  1       |    5   |    5     |   4
2  | expert 2 |  1       |    3   |    3     |   3
3  | expert 3 |  1       |    4   |    2     |   3
```

I select places with

```
$places = Place::all();
```

and used it

```
return view('place',compact('places'));
```

I need to use data from "rating" table with "places" and don't know how to do that

I need to find average of all values and average of each type of value AND use it with places.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asuming you're using atleast Laravel 5 you can make a has many relationship in your Place model.

Here is an example taken from the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many):

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Place extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the comments for the blog post.
     */
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Rating');
    }
}
```